# Matlab onehot to integers

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, indexing, one-hot-encoding

I want to convert a onehot array to an array of integer values in MATLAB. Given:

```
Y =  1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
```

I want to return:

```
new_y = 1
        2
        2
```

Comment: I found one way of doing it. Maybe there are one line alternatives? `[~ , new_y ] = max(Y)` , `new_y = new_y'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `find` and return only the column indices like so

```
Y = [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 1 0];

[~, new_y] = find(Y);   % output: [1; 2; 2] is the col indices of your 1s
```

Similarly you can return the row indices if your input was the transpose

```
[new_y, ~] = find(Y);   % output: [1; 2; 3] is the row indices of your 1s
```

Comment: @Herman Thanks for the question edit to make your desired behaviour less ambiguous, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The Neural Network toolbox of MATLAB has built-in functions for converting between one-hot vectors and indices: [`ind2vec()`](https://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/ind2vec.html) to create a one-hot matrix, and  [`vec2ind()`](https://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/vec2ind.html) to convert the one-hot matrix back to a vector of indices.

Note: `ind2vec` returns a sparse matrix. To convert it to a full matrix, you have to use the `full()` function.

```
>> Y = full(ind2vec([1, 2, 3]))

Y =    

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1

>> new_y = vec2ind(Y)

new_y =

     1     2     3
```